# How to run multiple batch files with one master batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-8.1, batch-file

I have three bat files I would like to run, in three different directories:

directory/bat1/bat1.bat

directory/bat2/bat2.bat

directory/bat3/bat3.bat

I would like to use one master .bat to start all of the other bats in their directories. I can't use call because I get errors because there are dependencies for each different bat in the directory. I tried using start but that doesn't work either, it just bring up a command prompt withing the folder.

I know this sounds a little confusing but all I want to do is use one single .bat file to run multiple .bat files independent from each other in their own directories.

Comment: Try `cd` to each directory in turn then run the batch file ...

Comment: What would that code look like? Would it be cd "directory/bat1/" start bat1.bat?

Comment: `cd c:\directory\bat1 && bat1.bat` then `cd c:\directory\bat2 && bat2.bat` etc

Comment: That did not work for me, it only ran the first batch file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found a solution! I used this code in order to get the bat to open the three different bat files independently:

```
cd "\directory\bat1\"
start bat1.bat
cd "\directory\bat2\"
start bat2.bat
cd "\directory\bat3\"
start bat3.bat
```

Comment: but you wrote in your question  "I tried using start but that doesn't work either, it just bring up a command prompt withing the folder."  <-- and then you answered it using start. So what was it?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I didn't word it correctly. For some reason when I just ran.    start \directory\bat1\bat1.bat it just opened a blank command prompt cded into the directory\bat1\ directory.

Comment: I tried this but after calling all the batch file, an endless loop of opening CMDs started to pop out

Answer (score 36):

If you use **start**, the other bat-files will create new process for each bat, and run them all at the same time.

```
cd "\directory\bat1\"
start bat1.bat
cd "\directory\bat2\"
start bat2.bat
cd "\directory\bat3\"
start bat3.bat
```

But if you want to run the next one after the last one is finished, you can use **call**

```
cd "\directory\bat1\"
call bat1.bat
cd "\directory\bat2\"
call bat2.bat
cd "\directory\bat3\"
call bat3.bat
```

don't forget the first \ at the beginning of the **cd** , otherwise it will try to change the directory into a subdirectory of the current working directory.

Answer (score 3):

So i struggled with this problem, and none of these solutions or other ones worked. What I wanted to do in a "master" batch file was access subfolders and run batchfiles in those folders sequentially. This is what I ultimately ended up doing,

```
cd Folder1
call batch_cmd.bat
cd ..
cd Folder2
call batch_cmd.bat
cd ..
```

etc. etc. etc.

This format worked fine for me since I was using javascript/nodejs to generate those commands and batch files.

If you want to do something entirely in batch files then I'd suggest you look up powershell scripts instead.

Comment: Instead of doing 
`cd ..
cd Folder2`
you could do this at once with `cd ..\Folder2`

Answer (score 0):

For me - it worked as

> ECHO Running a batch file..
>   :: Below is path without double quotes but ends with "\".
>   cd path-to-the-file1
>   :: Below is the batch filename without double quotes.
>   call batch-filename1
>
> :: Below is path without double quotes but ends with "\".
>   cd path-to-the-file2
>   :: Below is the batch filename without double quotes. 
>   call batch-filename2